# What is wrong with my sub-pipeline in appendpipe?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a lookup table bsm_string_new_overheat_records.csv

```
| inputlookup bsm_string_new_overheat_records.csv
| rename CCU_location AS overheat_location
| table _time overheat_location start_CCU_AMBI_TEMP start_time_secs end_CCU_AMBI_TEMP end_time_secs overheat_duration_minutes
```

Its content:

```
_time                   overheat_location   start_CCU_AMBI_TEMP start_time_secs end_CCU_AMBI_TEMP   end_time_secs   overheat_duration_minutes
2023-06-10 11:41:44 A10             29                      1686421604          23                  1686422504      15
2023-06-10 11:42:44 A10             29                      1686413444          23                  1686422564      152
2023-06-10 11:43:44 A10             29                      1686412844          23                  1686422624      163
2023-06-10 11:44:44 A10             29                      1686413984          23                  1686422684      145
2023-06-10 11:45:44 A10             29                      1686420584          23                  1686422744      36
```

I also have an `index==“battery_data” sourcetype=“battery_field_data”` that contains the battery data. From this I can compute the average temperature for a location (“A10”), with start_time_secs (1686421604), and end_time_secs (1686422504). Here is an example:

```
index="battery_data" sourcetype="battery_field_data"
    | rex field=Tag "^(?P<CCU_location>\w+)_BQMS\.\1\.((BMS_\1_(?P<tag_suffix>.*))|(MU(?P<MU_number>\d+)\.BMS_\1_MU\6_UNIT(?P<UNIT_number>\d+)_(?P<tag_type>.*)))"
    | where CCU_location=="A10"
    | eval start_time_secs=1686421604, end_time_secs=1686422504
    | where (tag_suffix == "CCU_AMBI_TEMP") AND (start_time_secs <= _time) AND (_time <= end_time_secs)
    | eval Value=round(Value*0.1, 2)
    | stats avg(Value) AS average_temperature_in_overheat latest(_time) AS _time latest(*) AS * BY CCU_location start_time_secs end_time_secs
    | table _time CCU_location start_time_secs end_time_secs average_temperature_in_overheat
```

yielding

```
_time                   CCU_location    start_time_secs     end_time_secs   average_temperature_in_overheat
2023-06-10 11:39:54.971 A10             1686421604          1686422504      17.45
```

I would like to compute the average temperature for each record in bsm_string_new_overheat_records.csv
with the following query,

```
| inputlookup bsm_string_new_overheat_records.csv
| rename CCU_location AS overheat_location
| appendpipe [ search
index="battery_data" sourcetype="battery_field_data"
    | rex field=Tag "^(?P<CCU_location>\w+)_BQMS\.\1\.((BMS_\1_(?P<tag_suffix>.*))|(MU(?P<MU_number>\d+)\.BMS_\1_MU\6_UNIT(?P<UNIT_number>\d+)_(?P<tag_type>.*)))"
    | where CCU_location==overheat_location
    | where (tag_suffix == "CCU_AMBI_TEMP") AND (start_time_secs <= _time) AND (_time <= end_time_secs)
    | eval Value=round(Value*0.1, 2)
    | stats avg(Value) AS average_temperature_in_overheat latest(_time) AS _time latest(*) AS * BY CCU_location start_time_secs end_time_secs
]
| table _time overheat_location CCU_location start_time_secs end_time_secs average_temperature_in_overheat start_CCU_AMBI_TEMP end_CCU_AMBI_TEMP overheat_duration_minutes
```

I’d expect one additional record of average temperature for each overheat record (total 5+5=10 records).
However, here is what I got:

```
_time                   overheat_location   CCU_location    start_time_secs end_time_secs   average_temperature_in_overheat start_CCU_AMBI_TEMP end_CCU_AMBI_TEMP   overheat_duration_minutes
2023-06-10 11:41:44     A10                                 1686421604      1686422504                                          29                      23                  15
2023-06-10 11:42:44     A10                                 1686413444      1686422564                                          29                      23                  152
2023-06-10 11:43:44     A10                                 1686412844      1686422624                                          29                      23                  163
2023-06-10 11:44:44     A10                                 1686413984      1686422684                                          29                      23                  145
2023-06-10 11:45:44     A10                                 1686420584      1686422744                                          29                      23                  36
```

None of the average temperature result is there.
What’s wrong with my above query?
Even with empty sub-pipeline in the body of appendpipe:

```
| inputlookup bsm_string_new_overheat_records.csv
| rename CCU_location AS overheat_location
| appendpipe [
]
| table _time overheat_location start_CCU_AMBI_TEMP start_time_secs end_CCU_AMBI_TEMP end_time_secs overheat_duration_minutes
```

Indeed, there are 5 + 5 records. At the least, the cardinality looks right:

```
_time                   overheat_location   start_CCU_AMBI_TEMP start_time_secs end_CCU_AMBI_TEMP   end_time_secs   overheat_duration_minutes
2023-06-10 11:41:44 A10             29                      1686421604          23                  1686422504      15
2023-06-10 11:42:44 A10             29                      1686413444          23                  1686422564      152
2023-06-10 11:43:44 A10             29                      1686412844          23                  1686422624      163
2023-06-10 11:44:44 A10             29                      1686413984          23                  1686422684      145
2023-06-10 11:45:44 A10             29                      1686420584          23                  1686422744      36
2023-06-10 11:41:44 A10             29                      1686421604          23                  1686422504      15
2023-06-10 11:42:44 A10             29                      1686413444          23                  1686422564      152
2023-06-10 11:43:44 A10             29                      1686412844          23                  1686422624      163
2023-06-10 11:44:44 A10             29                      1686413984          23                  1686422684      145
2023-06-10 11:45:44 A10             29                      1686420584          23                  1686422744      36
```

Comment: what is the connecting field between your lookup and your indexed data?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "connecting field".

I'm using the fields of overheat_location, start_time_secs, end_time_secs from the main search to constrain the sub-search in the sub-search in the body of appendpipe. Could they be considered "connecting fields"?

Comment: I mean what is common between the lookup and the indexed data? Ie, what field(s) connect them together?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other commands that use a subsearch, the `appendpipe` command does not run a new query.  Instead, it applies the commands in the subpipeline to the existing result set and creates new "rows" with the output.  If you need to run a search then you probably want `append`, just be sure to follow it with a `stats` command that merges the two result sets.

```
| inputlookup bsm_string_new_overheat_records.csv
| rename CCU_location AS overheat_location
| append [ search
index="battery_data" sourcetype="battery_field_data"
    | rex field=Tag "^(?P<CCU_location>\w+)_BQMS\.\1\.((BMS_\1_(?P<tag_suffix>.*))|(MU(?P<MU_number>\d+)\.BMS_\1_MU\6_UNIT(?P<UNIT_number>\d+)_(?P<tag_type>.*)))"
    | where CCU_location==overheat_location
    | where (tag_suffix == "CCU_AMBI_TEMP") AND (start_time_secs <= _time) AND (_time <= end_time_secs)
    | eval Value=round(Value*0.1, 2)
    | stats avg(Value) AS average_temperature_in_overheat latest(_time) AS _time latest(*) AS * BY CCU_location start_time_secs end_time_secs
]
| stats values(*) as * by <<some shared field>>
| table _time overheat_location CCU_location start_time_secs end_time_secs average_temperature_in_overheat start_CCU_AMBI_TEMP end_CCU_AMBI_TEMP overheat_duration_minutes
```

Comment: I wish the above proposal would work. But it doesn't. The sub-search inside the body for append would be first exected before the main search. Thus the values of overheat_location, start_time_secs, end_time_secs are all null. It's not the usual semantics that I'd expect that the sub-search would be executed in the context of the main search. 

That's why I had hoped that appendpipe would execute a sub-search with the values of overheat_location, start_time_secs, end_time_secs substantiated.

Comment: Where can I find more documentation of the detailed behavior of appendpipe? From Splunk documentation, the description is too vague:
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Appendpipe
"Appends the result of the subpipeline to the search results. Unlike a subsearch, the subpipeline is not run first. The subpipeline is run when the search reaches the appendpipe command. The appendpipe command is used to append the output of transforming commands, such as chart, timechart, stats, and top."

This description seems not excluding running a new sub-search.

Comment: In my first comment, I'd correct:
Thus the values of overheat_location, start_time_secs, end_time_secs in the sub-search are all null.

Comment: The subsearch specified in `append` does not run before the main search.  The definition of `append` is to put after so the subsearch runs after the main search, when the `append` command is reached.  IOW, the subsearch runs before the *command* it is invoked with so the subsearch runs then the results are appended.

Comment: It's normal after the `append` command for fields to be null.  That's because the results are from two sources that contain different fields.  The `stats` command remedies that by grouping the results by some shared field(s).